# How to extract n-1 dimension array from a n-dimension array thanks to a n-1 dimension array and without a loop?

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

My problem is pretty simple, but I can not seem to find a solution.
I have a n-dimension array A, and I would like to extract the n-1 dimension array B thanks to a n-1 dimension array of indices C. 
How could I do it, without a loop ?

For example :

```
A=array(1:12, dim=c(2,3,2))
A
, , 1
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    3    5
 [2,]    2    4    6

  , , 2
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    7    9   11
 [2,]    8   10   12

C=array(c(1,2,2,1,1,2),dim=c(2,3))
C
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    1
 [2,]    2    1    2
```

and finally I would like to find B (as something like "A[,,C]")

```
B
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    9    5
 [2,]    8    4    12
```

As if I have done

```
B 
           [,1]                 [,2]              [,3]
 [1,]    A[1,1,C[1,1]]   A[1,2,C[1,2]    A[1,3,C[1,3]]
 [2,]    A[2,1,C[2,1]]   ...
```

I have to do this in 5 dimensions, so if I could avoid to make loops...

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Comment: I'm not getting how you obtain `B`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Of course, C is the array of indices to take along the third dimension. For example B[1,1] = A[1,1, C[1,1]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try

```
library(reshape2)
matrix(A[as.matrix(melt(C))], ncol=ncol(C))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    9    5
#[2,]    8    4   12
```

Comment: The "melt" function perfectly responds to my needs. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I would solve this by index calculation: By adding `0:(length(C)-1)` to every [.,.,i]-slice (i=1,2 in your case) of `A` you get the indices for the first slice. If a multiplication of `C-1` with the length of `C` is done before and then `1` added, you will also get the correct indices of all other slices. The `-1` and `+1` operations compensate each other, hence we can express this very shortly:

```
ind <- as.vector((C-1) * length(C) + 1:length(C))
array(A[ind], dim = dim(C))
```

Comment: Thanks, but if my problem is in 5 dimensions and the dimension to extract is the fourth ? What could I use ?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
B<-A[cbind(c(row(C)),c(col(C)),c(C))]
dim(B)<-dim(C)
```